# How to lock cell using google script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a Google Spreadsheet that share to my staffs to record every single order details.
This is only example:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1r8_6S_jI-ZzL1GgZEur4ZVM51xqu3fWfnbFOHw3ZTZw/edit?usp=sharing

Every time the order is closed, I wish to protect whole order row to avoid mistaken edits.
In the example file I have a script code that I copied from some other posts(I couldn't find it anymore) but the demand between me and the original poster is kinda different so I edited the range but I still can't make it perfect.

Here's what I need:

1. If G2 = 1, A2:F2 protect to only owner can edit.
   When G2 is anything else,clear the protected range A2:F2.
   I need it to do the same thing in every single row until 2000.
   (G3 = 1 then protect A3:F3)
   (G4 = 1 then protect A4:F4)
   Something like this until 2000 row.
2. I want the same code applying to all 4 tab (Sheet1 to Sheet4)
3. I found that with my current script, if G2 = 1, everytime I edit something it will add a new range to the same range (A2:F2).I remember the original post is onOpen but I have to make it onEdit to make sure everything is protected well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this can help you. A few considerations first:

First of all, creating a Range is not a quick process, it requires from 0,5 to 1 second, so doing this for 2000 rows in 4 sheets (that's 8000 rows) it would take 1 or 2 hours, and that's way beyond the execution time [limit](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas#current_limitations) even if you were an Enterprise G Suite user.

The main problem with ranges is that they are stored in `SpreadsheetApp.ProtectionType.RANGE`, this creates an array of Ranges, so in order to delete an specific range when G is not 1, you have to compare the Row you edited with all the values of the Range array.

This script executes each time you edit a row, if it's protected (G = 1) it does nothing, if it's not and you change G = 1, then it protects the range A:F of that row. If you change the 1 in G, it deletes the protection. So this doesn't protect or unprotect each row of the 4 sheets, it only protects or unprotects the row you edit in any of the sheets.

```
 function onEdit() {
  var sprsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = sprsheet.getActiveSheet();
  var protections = sheet.getProtections(SpreadsheetApp.ProtectionType.RANGE);
  var col_G = sheet.getRange("G2:G2000").getValues();
  var edited_row = sheet.getActiveRange().getRow();
  var protected = false;
  var range_pos;
  modifyProtection(edited_row, protections, col_G, sheet, protected);

}

function modifyProtection(edited_row, protections, col_G, sheet, protected, range_pos){
  if (protections.length == 0 && col_G[edited_row - 2] == 1){ //In case there aren't ranges yet
    createRange(edited_row, sheet);

  } else {
      for (var i = 0; i < protections.length; i++){

          if (edited_row == protections[i].getRange().getRow()){
            range_pos = i;
            protected = true;

          }
  }
    if (protected && col_G[edited_row - 2] != 1){
          protected = false;
          deleteRange(range_pos, protections);        


    } else {
          if (!protected && col_G[edited_row - 2] == 1){
              protected = true;
              createRange(edited_row, sheet);
      }
    }
  }
}

function createRange(edited_row, sheet, protected){

   var range = sheet.getRange('A'+(edited_row)+':F'+(edited_row));
   var protection = range.protect().setDescription('Sample protected range');
   var me = 'your_email';//This will be the only editor of the protected ranges   
   protection.addEditor(me);  
   protection.removeEditors(protection.getEditors());

   if (protection.canDomainEdit()) {
       protection.setDomainEdit(false);
   }
}

function deleteRange(i, protections){
    protections[i].remove();
}
```

Comment: Hi Jes thanks a lot for helping me out!
It works well but just like you said, Sheet takes too long to do such things.
btw does Enterprise G Suite user helps improving Google sheets loading speed?
I found that more formula I added in a single spreadsheet the spreadsheet will just getting slower and slower.
I tried using different spreadsheet to separate the formula ( counting different things in different spreadsheet and at last return answer to a sheet)
It helps but the import range delay time is just too slow and not stable.
I'm looking for some other software that has cloud

Comment: I'm looking for some other software that has cloud sync like google sheet or some ways that can improve google sheet loading speed.
I'm willing to pay for better loading speed if google has such service.

Comment: You are welcome. A basic user has the same execution speed as an Enterprise, but the Enterprise can execute the same script for 30 minutes, while the Consumer has 6. That's why creating these ranges exceeds any execution time limit from Google. Regarding creating the formulas, you could considerate doing the calculus in the Script, as it's much faster and easy to manage. But that's another question you should post. Cheers!